# JAXB Enum Generating as VALUE_1 Instead of XSD String Names

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I have an XSD file with

```
<xsd:simpleType name="FieldName">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value=" " />
            <xsd:enumeration value="COMMON_NAME" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="IP_ADDRESS" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="ORIGINAL_ID" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="SITE_NAME" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

The JAXB class that this generated is a little weird as it generates the field value as

```
@XmlEnumValue("COMMON_NAME")
VALUE_1("COMMON_NAME"),
@XmlEnumValue("IP_ADDRESS")
VALUE_2("IP_ADDRESS"),
.
.
and so on.
```

Is there a way in the binding xjb file (some property or something), that would make it generate with string names rather than generic "VALUE_1". This is smaller example, there is another enum with more than 300 values in it! And this is an external XSD (owned by some other team in our organization), so I cant just go in and modify the XSD.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, from the moment that one of the values is not convertible to a Java Enum constant name, JAXB generates fallback names like VALUE_1, VALUE_2, etc.

This is the case when the values are numbers, like "1.2", 1.3", etc.

In your example the enumeration starts with value " ", no match for a Java constant name.

In those cases you will need to tell JAXB which Java Enum Constant name you want, for **every** enumeration value in that particular XSD enumeration restriction.

Like we did for the MODS 3.6 xsd:

```xml
<xs:element name="mods" type="modsDefinition"/>
<!--  -->
<xs:complexType name="modsDefinition">
    <xs:group ref="modsGroup" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:ID"/>
    <xs:attribute name="version">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="3.6"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="3.5"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="3.4"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="3.3"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="3.2"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="3.1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="3.0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

we configured the binding like this:

```xml
<bindings
    node="xs:complexType[@name='modsDefinition']/xs:attribute[@name='version']">
    <property name="version" />
    <bindings node="xs:simpleType">
        <typesafeEnumClass name="EnumModsVersion">
            <typesafeEnumMember name="V3_6" value="3.6"/>
            <typesafeEnumMember name="V3_5" value="3.5"/>
            <typesafeEnumMember name="V3_4" value="3.4"/>
            <typesafeEnumMember name="V3_3" value="3.3"/>
            <typesafeEnumMember name="V3_2" value="3.2"/>
            <typesafeEnumMember name="V3_1" value="3.1"/>
            <typesafeEnumMember name="V3_0" value="3.0"/>
        </typesafeEnumClass>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

to get this Java code:

```java
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlEnum
public enum EnumModsVersion {

    @XmlEnumValue("3.6")
    V3_6("3.6"),
    @XmlEnumValue("3.5")
    V3_5("3.5"),
    @XmlEnumValue("3.4")
    V3_4("3.4"),
    @XmlEnumValue("3.3")
    V3_3("3.3"),
    @XmlEnumValue("3.2")
    V3_2("3.2"),
    @XmlEnumValue("3.1")
    V3_1("3.1"),
    @XmlEnumValue("3.0")
    V3_0("3.0");
    private final String value;

    EnumModsVersion(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static ModsDefinition.EnumModsVersion fromValue(String v) {
        for (ModsDefinition.EnumModsVersion c: ModsDefinition.EnumModsVersion.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```